# Symfony 2.8 with WAMP - page won't load

Tags: php, symfony, wamp

I've been developing a web application using Symfony 2.8 and PHP internal server on Windows 7, and everything's been working fine. After switching to apache (WAMP), I cannot load any pages anymore - the little spinner in browser tab just keeps spinning and nothing happens. I've even added a limit to max_execution_time to 5 seconds (and tested it using phpinfo()), and it never gets hit! How is that even possible? Even worse, after trying to open my site once, some process keeps using my CPU even if I close the tab and turn wamp off - but it doesn't get displayed in Task Manager. It only stops using my CPU after I turn Wamp on and off several times.

There are no errors in error log and, so I don't have a clue what to do. I've already had a number of problems with Symfony (this is my first real project with it), which I've managed to solve, but this one seems totally uncomprehensible to me. The only little clue I have is a notice I get when I manually delete the cache:

Notice: Corrupt member variable name in C:\wamp\www\apc\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\AccessListener.php on line 70

If I'm not mistaken, this kind of notice might be common after a manual removal of cached files, but what's interesting is that this message (and a huge accompanying stacktrace) keeps being added to the bottom of the page as long as I keep it open. I guess there is some kind of an infinite loop thing going on.

Any help would truly be appreciated.

Btw I'm using a virtual hosting setup, and my entry in httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.8>
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\apc\web"
    ServerName apc.bgpixel
    <Directory "C:\wamp\www\apc\web">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm adding this because it is definitely one difference between using the internal PHP server (where you don't need to set anything of the kind) and using apache. Althoguh I wouldn't bet on it being the source of the problem.

Comment: I suggest you start debugging your system by first requesting a static file, for example an image or text file with http. If that still fails, then remove php support from the http servers configuration. This sounds like a typical issue with installations on MS-Windows system which, unlike all other systems these days, still do not have a software management system and package based installations.

Comment: About that CPU consumption: _why_ do you think that is the case of no process is shown to consume CPU cylces?

Comment: @arkascha I have a virtual hosting setup and all other sites I have work normally (none are using Symfony). And, out of desperation, I did try a few things like you are suggesting - adding an empty index.php, adding die() to app.php and even debugging symfony (which turned out difficult thanks to all the complexity and reflextion used in symfony code)

Comment: @arkascha no processes use my CPU in Task Manager -> Processes, but Task Manager -> Performance shows somewhere between 40-60% usage which is quite a lot (and I have a relativly capable CPU - i5-4690K)

Comment: Sounds like a pretty stupid process manager to me then. Sorry, no idea. Maybe that process manager only shows _some_ of the processes, for example your own, but not the system services?